# Selection of Minimum items Out of N items, Such that there should be M items in K consecutive items

Tags: php, math, combinations, combinatorics

I want a hint on a efficient algorithm of solving the following:
(Okay, The question was not that, I just made this for simplicity).
Example: Out of **N** Advert boards there should be **M** advert of a company in **K** consecutive boards. and the Adverts will be used such a way that only **MINIMUM** number of Adverts will be used
if N=3,K=2,M=1. The answer will be one 010;
if N=6, K=3, M=2 the answer will be 6.
011011,
011101,
011110,
101101,
101110,
110110.
I took the approach of Creating all the combinations(with binary approach) with iterative and recursive method.After that I filtered it. It is working well except if N is big it will crash.(as expected). So Is there any efficient method of solving these?
I just took another approach but it is not going to well .. :(

### Second approach

```
if($n%$k == 0){
$perm = $m*($n/$k);
}else{
$perm = $m*ceil($n/$k);
}
Then I will do the nCr... and now I'm lost
```

### First Approach

```
<?php
$n = $input1;$k = $input2;$l=$input3; $total = 0;
$flag = false;$arrays = array();$z=0;$min=$n;$x=0;

$total_permutations = pow(2,$n);
for($i=0;$i<$total_permutations;$i++){
    $binary = base_convert($i, 10, 2);
    $binary = str_pad($binary, $n,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        for($j=0;$j<=($n-$k);$j++){
            $flag = false;$x=0;
                for($m=0;$m<$k;$m++){
                    $x += intval($binary{$j+$m});
                }
            if($x<$l){
                $flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    if(!$flag){
        $arrays[$z]=str_split($binary);
        $arrays[$z] = array_map('intval', $arrays[$z]);
        $z++;
    echo $binary."<br />";
    }
    unset($binary);
}
$min = min(array_map('array_sum',$arrays));
echo "------------<br />";
foreach($arrays as $val){
    $sum = array_sum($val);
    if($sum == $min){
        echo implode("",$val);echo "<br>";
        $total++;
    }
}
return $total;

}
?>
```

Comment: Why `101` is not a solution for `N=3,K=2,M=1` ?

Comment: And I forgot to write the most important part ... "I Need The Minimum Number of items"

Comment: A dynamic programming solution would work in O(N*nCr(K,M)) time, (excellent for large N but small K,M); but surely there is a better way...

Comment: @torquestomp thank you for the reply(or comment). Will you please Elaborate what u just said?! or maybe a link for better understanding. Because coincidentally N is large and K,M is small in the values given. :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, here is one potential solution (Though, I would be very disappointed if there wasn't a better one)

1) First, calculate the minimum number of 1's needed in a valid solution.  (I believe this is simply `max(M, floor(n/k)*m + max(0, n%k-(k-m)))`.  The formula is derived from building a string one letter at a time, placing 0's whenever possible)

2) Now, assume N > K (otherwise the answer is trivial).
We define the sub-problem to be:  "Given a prefix P of length K, and a budget B of 1's to place, how many ways are there to fill out N characters whilst still enforcing the M rule?"

For example, consider that our string is "101XXXXXX", with K = 3, M = 2, and B = 4.  Here, N = 6, P = "101".  We solve this sub-problem like so:

```
a) Check if the budget is big enough in O(N) time.  Return 0 if it isn't
   If N=0, return 1 trivially
b) Set total possible solutions to 0
c) Set the first unknown character to 1.  Compute the new prefix P'
   (by stripping off the first character, and adding a "1" to the end),
   the new B' = B-1, the new N' = N-1, and solve the new sub-problem:
     Add its result to our total
d) Set the unknown character to 0 instead:  But only if the new prefix P'  
  (strip, add "0") has at least M 1's.  If so, set B' = B-1, N' = N-1,  
  and solve the new sub-problem.  Add its result to our total
e) Return the total
```

To solve the original problem, simply consider all possible prefixes P (all nCr(K,M) of them), and sum up the solutions to the derived sub-problems.  By caching the results to sub-problems based on unique inputs P, N, and B, we reduce the amount of duplicate work drastically.  Amortized analysis should show that the full solution runs in O(N*nCr(K,M)) time

Comment: Thank You... Awesome Answer! .. Just one request can you please give a small example?!I mean the steps of the process ..
And there are maybe better answers out there. But, this is sufficient for me!